# removing the .local in local network name serving

Tags: macos, nameserver, mdns

I have several local machines; I use a OSX 10.6 machine to do most of the serving. Annoyingly, it postfixes its network name with `.local`.

How would I set up a system so that  I could access it by its hostname?

---

server: httpd apache2 default install

I am accessing it with a web browser(surprisingly).

also when I ping my osx machine as `name`, it doesn't work; ping `name.local` does work.

Comment: Can you be more specific how you are trying to access it? What service? How are you connecting from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set up a DNS nameserver and configure your machines to look to it.

Software like [PowerDNS](http://wiki.powerdns.com/trac/wiki/PowerDNSFaq) should do the trick.

You will then need to configure PowerDNS to point to an upstream DNS resolver for queries outside of your LAN.

Finally, you will need to configure your hosts to look to your DNS server.

- If your machines have static addresses, then set their primary DNS address to the address of your DNS server.
- If your machines are assigned IP addresses via DHCP, just configure the DHCP server to hand out the address of your DNS server as the primary DNS addresses for your machines.  Then expire their addresses so every machines gets a new address, and gets the new DNS information.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to change your hostname. On OS X, open up the terminal, and...

```
sudo scutil --set HostName your_new_hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

What router / DNS server do you have running on your network?

The .local is for Zero Configuration aka Bonjour networking.  My macintoshes at home are accessible, with and without the ".local".  It's equivalent to having a extra cname, or host entry...

How are you trying to access the Macintosh?  What OS, and what application?

You shouldn't have to remove the .local....

Comment: windows vista; I ssh and http into the osx 10.6

Comment: DNS?  Does your router support local DNS?